# php-zip with php 8.1.8

Tags: 22.04, php, zip

I'm trying to install php-zip and i have already installed php 8.1.8 on ubuntu 22.04.1.

When i try to install it, it fails and the error message says:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> php8.1-zip : Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.5) but 8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed

As i understand, the php-zip supports only versions up to 8.1.2.

Is there a workaround to install it or i have to downgrade to php 8.1.2?

Comment: You have mixed sources for php. Make sure You disabled the "sury" ppa. Run `apt update` and then try to install `php8.1-zip`.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I've removed it by running `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php`, then ran `apt update` but i got the same error when trying to install the `php8.1-zip`

Comment: Removing the repository will not remove the version of PHP that's installed. If you've made the effort to install 8.1.8, then that's the version that's still installed on the machine, meaning that the default Ubuntu repositories cannot offer you a (verified) compatible `php-zip` package. If you need PHP 8.1.8 to be on your machine, the easiest way to do this would be via Docker packages. The Ondrej repository is great for a number of things, but can sometimes have gaps like the one you've experienced 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem by installing also php8.0 at the server and then installing php8.0-zip. After that, i've changed the php version in nginx and everything worked smoothly without downtime and without having to uninstall 8.1 first